# Attempting to use two different user inputs to get information from two lists in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am having issues with trying to get two users inputs from two lists. I will post code and try to explain.

I have multiple inputs for users to choose options. In this case, it is choosing:
1.) a Rack
2.) an FDP on that rack
3.) a MOD inside that FDP

I do some math on these to get a 'unique identifier variable' that I then use to choose a value from a list. This is where I am running into issues. I want that value from the list to then be added to the next user input to then combine them to look through another list. Example:

```
#this is the list that looks at unique identifier variable. say I got 153, I would get water
selector = {
    39:"test",
    43:"r01c07f02-mb",
    47:"r01c07f03-mc",
    153:"water"
}
```

I then want 'water' to have [x] added to it, where x is the last user input, to then look at other lists:

```
water = {
    1:{'Customer':'CID'},
    2:{'Customer2':'CID2'},
    3:"Third Option"
}

otherList = {
    1:{'Customer3':'CID3'},
    2:{'Customer4':'CID4'},
    3:"TESTERS TESTEST"
}
```

so if the user got 153 as the unique identifier, and then entered 3 at the last input, I want "Third Option" printed. however, I can only get it to print 'water[3]' or any of the options, but I can't get it to actually print the value IN water[3]. Here is the code I am using to combine them, I know it is wrong but I don't know how.

```
def getInfo(arg1):
    testVar = "blank" #just bs for testing
    testVar = selector[arg1]
    return testVar #returns whatever is in selector[arg1] spot, the unique identifier (uIdent) is passed as arg1 below


u = str(sInfo) #turning the last user input into a string because you cant add str to int (think this is where I am messing up)
conCat1 = "concat1 blank"
print("Here is first try: ")
print(conCat1) #will print 'concat1 blank'
conCat1 = getInfo(uIdent) + '[' + u + ']' 
print("Here is second try: ") #will print whatever the value was next to unique ident in the selector list, + [sInfo], so water[3] or test[1] for examples
print(conCat1)
```

Anyone have some ideas to help me out, or to point me in the right direction? Please let me know if you need additional information, or if I should post the whole code (its only ~150 lines of amateur code). I didn't want to clutter this post up more than I am sure it already is by posting full code, but will if asked!

Edit: basically is there a way to turn a type string of variable[x] to a type dict so that it prints the value IN variable[x] and not the actual string variable[x]

Comment: I think posting full code might help, I don't quite get what you want to do.
Aside from that: please look into PEP8, your names are not like they should be in Python. And for concatenation of strings use f-strings (just google it, they're fairly easy to use) as they're more readable and faster or if you don't use Python 3.6+ string.format

Comment: Just read your edit: you basically want a dict that's values are dicts?

Comment: I just want it so I can kind of dynamically get a different value based on what the user is inputting without having to hardcode in a million if statements or something. I want this scaleable. My variable names and the organization of the code will change, currently messy because I am adding and deleting temp variables to test as I go along.

right now how I have it the final value I get is a string that says, for example, "water[3]". I want it to give that same thing, water[3], but I don't want it as a string, I want it as the actual value in the water list at position [3].

Comment: also @SV-97 i see what you are saying with PEP8 stuff, I looked it up. I will follow the guidelines listed there from now on, thank you.

Comment: I think you want a nested dict, put the dict water as value into selector and select from that at the second input. Alternatively make dict of your other dicts with strings as keys and select directly on input string

Comment: @SV-97 I think I looked into that and had to rule it out because I need the first three user inputs to set the correction rack,fdp,mod and then the last one to set strands within that rack,fdp,mod based on what they selected, and then spit out the two values, Customer and CID. Is this still possible by nesting?

Comment: Well you don't necessarily need the nested dict but some collection. You could also use regex (re module from the standard library) to extract name and index and use getattr on a class that holds your dicts (water etc.)

Or you could use `eval` but then you have to sanitize the input, otherwise it'll be a really big security risk (Raymond hettinger (Python core dev) said that using eval is most times avoidable and should be avoided but can be a really powerful tool at times and thus is used in (c)python itself)

Comment: I'll look into some of those, thank you. I am not too worried about security because this will be used by myself and one or two others just to reduce some walking around the DC to check which circuits are what bulkhead etc. I appreciate your help with this @SV-97 !

Comment: @NickAdams here you are getting `water` as string . so performing `water[1]` will give you error. you have to write a new function to identify the dictionary is there or not ( ie there is dict name water) if yes then get save the value in new variable  `new_var = water['user_input']` . in another way you can create a new nested dictionary , instead of writing a individual dictionary